# How can I speed up Cython code to compute conditional log likelihood of dirichlet?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, cython

I have a function that computes the conditional (on kth alpha) log likelihood of a dirichlet distribution.  I have it written in Cython and compiled, but my code calls it about 12M times and it seems to be the bottleneck, so I'm hoping to speed it up.

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
import math
DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

def logFullConAlphaK(np.ndarray p,np.ndarray alpha, np.int k):
    assert p.dtype == np.float64 and alpha.dtype == np.float64
    cdef double t1=sum(np.log(p))
    cdef DTYPE_t y=((alpha[k-1]-1)*t1)-np.log(alpha[k-1])+(p.shape[0]*
                   (math.lgamma(sum(alpha))- math.lgamma(alpha[k-1])))
return y
```

I compile the Cython into a .pyd file that I use in my code.  Any thoughts on how I can speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: When asking for code optimization, please always include sample data and provide timings for your code. This makes it much easier for others to help you.
That said, use `np.sum` instead of the built-in `sum` in high performance numpy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) By declaring the data types and dimensions of your input arrays and for `p.shape[0]`:

```
def logFullConAlphaK(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] p,
                     np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] alpha, int k):

    ...
    cdef int tmp
    tmp = p.shape[0]
```

2) By using C functions instead of Python functions from the module `math`:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double log(double x) nogil
```

3) Using NumPy's `np.ndarray.sum()` method

4) Using Cython directives to avoid some overhead

Altogether:

```
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#cython: nonecheck=False

import math

cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double log(double x) nogil    

DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

def logFullConAlphaK(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] p,
                     np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] alpha, int k):
    assert p.dtype == np.float64 and alpha.dtype == np.float64
    cdef double t1
    cdef int tmp

    t1 = np.log(p).sum()
    tmp = p.shape[0]

    cdef DTYPE_t y=((alpha[k-1]-1)*t1)-log(alpha[k-1])+(tmp*
                   (math.lgamma(alpha.sum()) - math.lgamma(alpha[k-1])))

    return y
```

Some performance comparisons among the OP's original solution, @cel's solution and mine:

```
In [2]: timeit solOP(a, b, 10)
1000 loops, best of 3: 273 µs per loop

In [3]: timeit solcel(a, b, 10)
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.5 µs per loop

In [4]: timeit solS(a, b, 10)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.8 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Take this (probably completely unrealistic) sample data:

```
n = 1000000
p = np.random.rand(n)
alpha = np.random.rand(n)
k = 12
```

I get following timings:

`%timeit logFullConAlphaK(p, alpha, k)` -> `1 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop`

`%timeit logFullConAlphaK_opt(p, alpha, k)` -> `100 loops, best of 3: 13.3 ms per loop`

This version already gives you an order of magnitude in speed. Note that *almost* all speedup comes from using `np.sum` over the built-in `sum`. All other changes are just for cleaner code, they do not have an impact on the speed.

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
import math

def logFullConAlphaK_opt(double[:] p, double[:] alpha, int k):
    cdef double t1=np.sum(np.log(p))
    cdef double y=((alpha[k-1]-1)*t1)-np.log(alpha[k-1])+(p.shape[0]*
                   (math.lgamma(np.sum(alpha))- math.lgamma(alpha[k-1])))
    return y
```

Comment: not all the speed up comes from using `np.sum()`, also from the fact you're using memory views with specified data types

Comment: @SaulloCastro, I see very similar timings here for the typed memory view vs. numpy array version. Probably it was not a good idea to say `all` of the speed comes from the `np.sum`, but certainly this is the relevant part.
I would be interested in seeing timings comparing your answer, my answer and the original code.

Comment: I've added a time comparison in my answer and by adding the other fine tunnings mine was twice as fast as yours

Comment: Thank you both!  This is super helpful for this code and in general.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: @hashimba, glad we could help. If your problem is solved, please consider marking one of the answers as the accepted answer. I would recommend accepting the answer of Saullo Castro here.